# How to open Modal in React JS Unsplash Website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to build an Image Gallery using Unsplash API , React JS & Styled Components

This is how the website looks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuec4.jpg)

When I click on the Image Card I want a Modal to Open which consists of details but I dont get how can I do that

Code for Image Gallery Component :

```
    import React from 'react'
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import ImgCard from './ImgCard';
    import axios from "axios";
    import { useState , useEffect } from "react";
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import Modal from './Modal';
    
    const Container = styled.div`
    margin-top: 1rem;
    column-count: 3;
    column-width: 33%;
    
    @media(max-width:1000px){
      column-count:2;
      column-width:50%;
    }
    
    @media(max-width:768px){
      column-count:1;
      column-width:100%;
    }
    
    
    `;
    
    const ImgGallery = styled.div``;
    
    
    const Images = () => {
    
        let text = useSelector((state) => state.text);
        const [image, setImage] = useState([]);
    
        const searchURL = `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=${text}&per_page=5&client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_API_KEY}` 
    
    
        const url = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_API_KEY}&per_page=5&page=1`
    
        useEffect(()=>{
            setImage([]);
            if(text === ''){
            axios.get(url).then((response)=>{
               setImage(response.data);
              }).catch((err)=>{
                  console.log(err);
              })
            }else{
              axios.get(searchURL).then((response)=>{
                setImage(response.data.results);
               }).catch((err)=>{
                   console.log(err);
               })
            }
          },[url,text]);
        
         const [openModal,setOpenModal] = useState(false);
         const [index,setIndex] = useState(0);
    
         const showModal = () => {
            // setIndex(index);
            // setOpenModal(true);
            console.log('hello');
         }
    
    
      return (
          <Container>
            <Modal openModal={openModal} arr={image[index]}/>
             {  
                image.map((item,index)=>( 
                <ImgGallery key={item.id}>
                    <ImgCard link={item.urls.full} user={item.user} likes={item.likes} onClick={()=>showModal()}/>
                </ImgGallery>
                ))
             }
        </Container>
      )
    }
    
    export default Images
```

Code for Modal Component:
The modal component should have the details of Image Item I clicked on.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ThumbUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbUp';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

const Container = styled.div`
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height:95vh;
border: 1px solid lightgrey;
border-radius: 0.5rem;
overflow: hidden;
/* display: ${({ isOpen }) => (isOpen ? 'flex' : 'none')}; */
display:none;
margin: 1rem;
align-items: center;
background: white;
z-index: 10;
`;

const Image = styled.img`
flex: 1;
object-fit: cover;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
`;


const Details = styled.div`
position: relative;
flex: 1;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
gap: 2rem;
padding: 1rem;
align-items: flex-start;
`;

const User = styled.div`
display: flex;
align-items: center;
gap: 0.8rem;
`;

const UserDetails = styled.div`
display: flex;
width:100%;
align-items:right;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 0rem 1rem;
`;

const UserInfo = styled.div`
display: flex;
align-items:left;
flex-direction: column;
`;

const UserImage = styled.img`
width: 3rem;
height: 3rem;
border-radius: 50%;
`;

const Likes = styled.div`
display: flex;
align-items: center;
gap: 0.5rem;
`;

const LikesCount = styled.p``;

const Name = styled.p`
font-weight: 600;
`;

const UserName = styled.p`
color:gray;
`;

const ImageDesc = styled.p`
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
gap: 1rem;
`;

const Close = styled.div`
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
top: -10rem;
right: 2rem;
`;

const Desc = styled.p``;
const AltDesc = styled.p``;
const Date = styled.p``;


const Modal = () => {
  
  return (
    <Container>
        <Image/>
        <Details>
        <Close>
            <CloseIcon fontSize='large'/>
        </Close>
        <UserDetails>
              <User>
                  <UserImage src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/9833110/pexels-photo-9833110.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1'/>
                 <UserInfo>
                    <Name>nilay</Name>
                    <UserName>@nilay</UserName>
                </UserInfo>
             </User>
             <Likes>
                 <LikesCount>2.3k</LikesCount>
                 <ThumbUpIcon fontSize='medium'/>
             </Likes>
        </UserDetails>
        <ImageDesc>
            <Desc>description</Desc>
            <AltDesc>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab voluptatem nesciunt quaerat laudantium reprehenderit, magni a voluptates saepe sit est harum. Accusantium quasi numquam adipisci officiis, expedita possimus fuga voluptas!
            </AltDesc>
            <Date>
              24th March
            </Date>
        </ImageDesc>
        </Details>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

The Code Structure is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuec4.jpg)

The Modal Looks Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2QOb.png)

Answer (score 0):

const [modalState,setModalState] = useState(null);

```
     const showModal = (data) => {
   //this will add the selected image object into modalState
      setModalState(image)
     }


  return (
      <Container>
        <Modal openModal={modalState}/>
         {  
            image.map((item,index)=>( 
            <ImgGallery key={item.id}>
                <ImgCard link={item.urls.full} user={item.user} likes={item.likes} onClick={()=>showModal(item)}/>
            </ImgGallery>
            ))
         }
    </Container>
  )
```